# Why is Outlook Interop opens outlook on my Pc even though some one else is accessing the link on their PC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, outlook

I have created a function to share feedback with Agents who handled the Chats from Customer.
Feedback needs to be shared by Email from outlook. I tested the code and it does work great on my local PC.
Issue comes when some one else opens the WebApp on their local PC, and audit the Chat.
Some one else auditing chat on their Local PC opens Outlook to share feedback on my PC instead of opening on their own PC.

Can some one please help with the below code, and help me understand what is causing this to happen?
And, How can I resolve this?

Feedback Action method

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ShareFeedback(Chat model)
        {
            int id = model.ChatId;

            var q1yes = "30";
            var q1no = "0";

            var q2yes = "10";
            var q2no = "0";

            var q3yes = "25";
            var q3no = "0";

            var q4yes = "35";
            var q4no = "0";

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            int dtoId;

            using (Db db = new Db())
            {
                
                Chat dto = db.Chats.Where(x => x.ChatId == id).FirstOrDefault();
                dto.Feedback = model.Feedback;
                dto.FeedbackDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                

                if(model.Question1 == "Yes")
                {
                    dto.Question1 = q1yes;
                }
                else
                {
                    dto.Question1 = q1no;
                }

                if (model.Question2 == "Yes")
                {
                    dto.Question2 = q2yes;
                }
                else
                {
                    dto.Question2 = q2no;
                }

                if (model.Question3 == "Yes")
                {
                    dto.Question3 = q3yes;
                }
                else
                {
                    dto.Question3 = q3no;
                }

                if (model.Question4 == "Yes")
                {
                    dto.Question4 = q4yes;
                }
                else
                {
                    dto.Question4 = q4no;
                }


                dto.ErrorGrade = model.ErrorGrade;

                if (model.ErrorGrade == "Low")
                {
                    float total = float.Parse(dto.Question1) + float.Parse(dto.Question2) + float.Parse(dto.Question3) + float.Parse(dto.Question4);
                    dto.QualityScore = total;
                }
                if (model.ErrorGrade == "Medium")
                {
                    float total = float.Parse(dto.Question1) + float.Parse(dto.Question2) + float.Parse(dto.Question3) + float.Parse(dto.Question4);
                    float medtotal = total / 2;

                    dto.QualityScore = medtotal;
                }

                if (model.ErrorGrade == "High")
                {
                    float total = 00;
                    dto.QualityScore = total;
                }

                if(model.ErrorGrade == null)
                {
                    float total = float.Parse(dto.Question1) + float.Parse(dto.Question2) + float.Parse(dto.Question3) + float.Parse(dto.Question4);
                    dto.QualityScore = total;
                }

                var uName = User.Identity.Name;

                User userDTO = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username == uName).FirstOrDefault();
                dto.FeedbackSharedBy = userDTO.Username;
                dto.AuditorEmail = userDTO.Email;
                

                db.SaveChanges();

                dtoId = dto.ChatId;
                
            }
            using (Db db = new Db())
            {
                Chat dto = db.Chats.Find(dtoId);

                Application app = new Application();
                MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

                if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
                { 
                
                mailItem.Subject = "Feedback: Chat handled on " + dto.ChatCreateDateTime + " For Customer " + dto.CustName;
                mailItem.To = dto.Email;
                mailItem.CC = "saurabhwa@cybage.com;sagargo@cybage.com;anacletem@cybage.com;riyazsh@cybage.com";
                mailItem.HTMLBody = "Hello " + dto.FirstName + "<br /><br />" + " <b>Res Time:</b> " + string.Format("<b>{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}</b>", dto.ChatEndDateTime - dto.ChatStartDateTime)
                 + " <b>AHT:</b> " + string.Format("<b>{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}</b>", dto.ChatEndDateTime - dto.ChatCreateDateTime) + " <b>Promptness:</b> " + string.Format("<b>{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}</b>", dto.ChatCreateDateTime - dto.ChatStartDateTime) + "<br/><br/>" + "Your score for this Chat audit is : " + "<b>" + dto.QualityScore + "%</b>" + "<br /><br />" + "<b>Feedback:</b>" + "<br /><br />" + dto.Feedback;
                mailItem.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
                mailItem.Display(false);
                }
            }

                return RedirectToAction("StartQMS");
        }
```

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, of course, your code is executed on your *server*, not on the *client* machine.

Besides the fact that you are using Outlook from a Windows service (IIS), which is a big no-no, you need to run the code on the client side, e.g. from a Java script in a page served by your server to the client browser.

And you cannot use Outlook from JS, unless you are running in IE, and your site is trusted. The best you can do is provide the user with a "mailto:" link that can pop up a new email window with the pre-populated subject, body, and recipients.

Comment: In fact, using Outlook at all for this is probably not the best idea.  +1 for the mailto: link.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer. Have use mailto instead and thats working for now

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, yes it does help a lot.